# Knowing when DataBinding is completed

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, datagridview

I've used the `System.ComponentModel.BindingList` as the `DataGridView.DataSource` in my app. The list is quite large and takes some seconds to be painted on the `DataGridView`. So, I need to know when data-binding (**included painting**) procedure finishes to do some stuff. I tried `DataBindingComplete` event, but it occurs right after setting a value to the `DataSource` property.

Thanks in advance.

---

***UPDATE:***

**1.** Generating binding-list **[** Getting data from Database **]** ► ~1 sec

**2.** Setting it to `DataSource` **[** Binding **]** ► ~1 sec *(The `DataBindingComplete` is raised right now.)*

**3.** Painting **[** Displaying data in the `DataGridView` **]** ► ~5 sec

Comment: well `DataBindingComplete` seems right but you need to expand on what issue you faced and why it didn't work out particularly

Comment: Dear @V4Vendetta: As I mentioned above, the `DataBindingComplete` works good. But when it's raised, the `DataGridView` still needs to paint. The painting procedure is a time consuming process and I'd like to know when it finishes. Please let me know if it isn't clear enough.

Comment: This event is raised when the contents of the data source change or when the value of the `DataSource`, `DataMember`, or `BindingContext` property changes.This event must be improved.At least this event fired 4 times to one running circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was as easy as described!

```
bool bindingCompleted = false;

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingList1;
}

void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    bindingCompleted = true;
}

void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (bindingCompleted)
    {
       bindingCompleted = false;

       // do some stuff.. 
    }
}
```